# Merge some of the Vim's tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

Could we merge some of the Vim's tags, specifically:

- [vim-plugins](/questions/tagged/vim-plugins) and [vim-plugin](/questions/tagged/vim-plugin)
- [vim](/questions/tagged/vim), [vim-registers](/questions/tagged/vim-registers) (too small, only 3 questions) and [fugitive.vim](/questions/tagged/fugitive.vim) (a plugin, not big enough IMO, nor generating big enough traffic)